How to sort two columns in pandas dataframe and draw the heatmap from resulting dataframe?
I am trying to draw the heatmap from dataframe below:



methods
sub_1
sub_2
sub_3
sub_4
.....
distance
count_0




m1
0
2
2
1
.....
0
20


m2
1
2
2
1
.....
7
22


m3
1
2
2
1
.....
26
12


m4
0
2
2
0
.....
21
10


m5
0
2
2
0
.....
17
5



in this dataframe, methods are clustering methods applied, sub_* is the customers and associated values are labels assigned by each method, distance is how far each method from overall label assignment(from ensemble result, see figure attached), count_0 represents how many customers are assigned in cluster 0.
Now, I want to sort the dataframe using distance and count_0 columns and draw the heatmap. Following code I tried that generates the heatmap but with one key only i.e. distance. When sort by two keys, I want all red color together, white color together and black color together in heatmap (see figure attached).
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(40,6))
df = df.sort_values(by=['distance', 'count_0'], ascending=[True, True])

svm = sns.heatmap(df.iloc[:,0:546], ax=ax, xticklabels=False, yticklabels=True, linewidths=0.4, annot_kws={"size": 16}, cbar_kws={"shrink": 0.3})

ax.set_xlabel("Customer IDs", fontsize=30)
ax.hlines(y = 1, xmin = 0, xmax = 550, colors = 'white', lw = 10)

for i in range(2,10):
    ax.hlines(y = i, xmin = 0, xmax = 550, colors = 'white', lw = 4)

figure = svm.get_figure()
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=30, labelbottom = False, bottom=False, top = False, labeltop=True)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=30)
plt.show()

Following output is generated:


You need to sort the dataframe accordingly before plotting and apply the correct colormap. So  both the distance and count_0 columns and to maintain the grouping of colors. Here is an example:
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'methods': ['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5'],
    'sub_1': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    'sub_2': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'sub_3': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'sub_4': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    'distance': [0, 7, 26, 21, 17],
    'count_0': [20, 22, 12, 10, 5]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.sort_values(by=['distance', 'count_0'], ascending=[True, True])

from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("custom_cmap", ["black", "white", "red"], N=256)

# Set up the heatmap
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))  

svm = sns.heatmap(df.iloc[:, 1:5],  
                  ax=ax,
                  cmap=cmap,
                  xticklabels=True,  
                  yticklabels=df['methods'],  
                  linewidths=0.4,
                  annot_kws={"size": 16},
                  cbar_kws={"shrink": 0.3})

ax.set_xlabel("Customer IDs", fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel("Clustering Methods", fontsize=15)

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    ax.hlines(y=i, xmin=0, xmax=len(df.columns) - 1, colors='white', lw=2)

# Adjust tick parameters
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=12, labelbottom=False, bottom=False, top=False, labeltop=True)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()

which gives

EDIT
Here is a solution that takes your original data and only the 10 first columns and the last 4 (btw, you do not regard count_2, count_3 etc.?):
count_0

which gives


Thank you for your answer. It works with the given sample dataset, but not working with full dataset I have with many customers. I am getting the same results as above.

Do add a sample dataframe containing several customers.

I have added the link for dataset file. See below the uploaded image above.

posted an edit. Unclear if it is what you are looking for. Let me know.

Thanks @Serge for the answer. What I want is, at the right side of the heatmap all red should be together, all black should be together, and all peach (white) should be together. Actually, I want to sort by distance and by group (red, white, black). That's what I want in the heatmap. Try with whole dataset, it gives above heatmap.
